# If non-empty player has a winning strategy in Banach-Mazur game BM(X), then it also has in BM(Y)?

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, game-theory, infinite-games

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous, open, surjection function and second player (non-empty) has a winning strategy (not important which one, say for simplicity stationery st.) in $BM(X)$. Then can we say the player has the same strategy in $BM(Y)$ ?

My attempts: 1) To say yes, $\sigma_Y(U)=f(\sigma_X(f^{-1}(U)))$ while $\sigma_i$ is stationery st. which depends on only last move of the opponent in $BM(i)$. But it didn't work.

2)To say no, Trying to find a continuous, open, surjection function from a scattered space to rational numbers.

Some definitions right here https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/the-banach-mazur-game/

At first I asked the question right here but no one answered yet https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531030/if-non-empty-player-has-a-winnig-strategy-in-banach-mazur-game-bmx-then-it-al

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question has been on MSE for less than a day - generally one should wait longer before moving to MO.

Comment: It seems that for non-stationary strategies your first attempt should work after a suitable modification taking intersections of preimages with the open sets suggested by the strategy $\sigma_X$.

Answer (score 3):

Topological spaces $X$ for which the second player (Non-empty) has a winning strategy in the Banach-Mazur game $BM(X)$ are called *weakly $\alpha$-favorable* by [White](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-050-01/S0002-9939-1975-0367941-0/S0002-9939-1975-0367941-0.pdf) and 
*Choquet* by [Kechris](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk#v=onepage&q&f=false).

According to [White](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-050-01/S0002-9939-1975-0367941-0/S0002-9939-1975-0367941-0.pdf), a open continuous image of a weakly $\alpha$-favorable space is weakly $\alpha$-favorable.